# illegal character in firefox when passing hex colour into a function

Tags: javascript, string, escaping

I have a function call and I am trying to pass a hex color (#000000) to a function but I keep getting an illegal character call in firebug and the function is failing.

I am assuming it is the '#' at the beginning of the colour thats causing this.

should I :

a, escape the hash

b, just pass the colour code minus the hash

the problem I have with each is

a, when I try to escape I am having an issue as the colour is a substring of a variable and the escape character makes the substring call not work

```
var linecolor="\"+content.substr(content.search("#"),7);
```

b, when I pass just '000000' to the function, it is received as just '0'

any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your code? or the function which expect the hex color?

Comment: It receives 0 when you pass 000000, because it interacts it like integer, try using string instead of var and then pass "000000" as a string :)

Comment: @Gintas K ok I changed the line to var linecolor=new String(content.substr((content.search("#")+1),6)); but it still reads it as a interger on the other side

Comment: @Moazzam Khan the code is var linecolor=content.substr(content.search("#"),7); changeshapelinecolor("+i+","+linecolor+"); and the function that recieves it is function changeshapelinecolor(i,content){ 
 alert("i="+i+" content="+content);
 
}

Comment: Can you show us that function then?

Comment: @GintasK  changeshapelinecolor(i,content){
 alert("i="+i+" content="+content); 
} the function has nothing but an alert in it at the moment

Comment: What's 'i'? And what do you receive in the alert box?

Comment: are you not just passing two strings here  - `changeshapelinecolor("+i+","+linecolor+");`

Comment: i is irrelevant to this question, its a character that I need to pass to the function. I am just passing two strings and then I will manipulate the strings in the function, but back to the question, the string is either illegal is I pass a hash and it loses the 5 '0's if I pass the 0's. in the alert i receive i=136 content=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var linecolor = new String(content.substr((content.search("#")+1),(content.search("#")+7)); 
function showColor(linecolor){
alert(" content="+linecolor); 
}
showColor(linecolor);
```

Comment: with a slight variation to the first line var linecolor = new String(content.substr((content.search("#")+1),6)); this worked many thanks

Comment: no problem :) that second index that you pass to the .substr method is the index of the end of substring, not the number of symbols to substring :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying something like this?

```
var content = "#222222"

function showColor(content){
 alert(" content="+content); 
}

showColor(content);
```

Comment: yes, but content is a substring of another string that is "<div id="shapebox149" style="width:100%;height:100%;border:0;border-left:3px;border-style:solid;border-color:#FFFFFF;"></div>" I am trting to extract the border-color and send to the function